# Multiple CSV Python sort

Tags: python, sorting

Thanks for the help so far!  I got up to this point in the code.

```
import glob
import csv
import sys
import array

x=1
signs=array.array('i',(0,)*31) 
files = glob.glob('./*.csv')
file = open("all.csv", 'w') 

for row in files: 
    if x<30: 
        signs[x]= x 
        x=x+1 

print (signs[x])
file.close()
```

I have problems with printing the whole array.  As I said, There are 29 files with 30 values each in the model :
                    1,2
                    2,9
                    3,20
                    4,6
                    5,2
There is no particular order or anything and numbers do repeat themselves.  I need to print out the numbers and how many of them have actually repeated themselves.  I seem to create the file all.csv but it appears to be empty.  I am really new to python please don't rage at me.  I searched for about 8 hours now (including previous code block which I deleted) but I appear to be stuck.

Comment: Could you give a short example of one of the input files please? Are there 30 values in a single row, or 30 rows or something else?

Comment: 1,2
2,6
3,9
4,17
and so on to 30,something
the something is no larger then 29 but could be 29

Comment: This isn't valid Python -- neither `i=0:` or `i++` work.  It also looks like you're trying to read from a csv file, "all.csv", which you open for writing (and therefore erase before you read from it.)

Comment: I dont know what is valid python , I am really new to it and some of the most basic stuff arent avaivable could I write i=i+1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: iterate over each number in each file and increment a counter that is stored in a dictionary. Print out the results sorted by the dictionary keys (which are the numbers encountered in the csv files).

```
import csv, glob, sys

from collections import defaultdict

files = [open(f) for f in glob.glob('user./[1-29].csv')]
#files = [open('input1','r')]
counts = defaultdict(int)

for f in files:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        for num in line:
            counts[int(num)] += 1

for key,val in sorted(counts.items()):
    print key, val
```